# Custom Report using Business Intelligence Development Studio FetchXML

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I want to create a `custom` report which will display all associated `Products` of all/any `Order`. That means in Order page its showing all Orders and associated Products, and in any Order record page it should display only the Products associated with that Order.

Previously I did that using report wizard.It was working as I wanted.

[image]

But I am not able to do it in Business Intelligence Development Studio.

this is the FetchXML

```xml
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="salesorderdetail">
    <attribute name="productid" />
    <attribute name="productdescription" />
    <attribute name="priceperunit" />
    <attribute name="quantity" />
    <attribute name="extendedamount" />
    <attribute name="salesorderdetailid" />
    <order attribute="productid" descending="false" />
    <link-entity name="salesorder" from="salesorderid" to="salesorderid" alias="ad">
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="salesorderid" operator="eq">

        </condition>
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

How I can modify this XML so that it will work like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am able to do it, using sub query.

This it the Sub query fetchXML:

```xml
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="salesorderdetail">
    <attribute name="productid" />
    <attribute name="productdescription" />
    <attribute name="priceperunit" />
    <attribute name="quantity" />
    <attribute name="extendedamount" />
    <attribute name="salesorderdetailid" />
    <order attribute="productid" descending="false" />
    <link-entity name="salesorder" from="salesorderid" to="salesorderid" alias="af">
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="salesorderid" operator="eq" uitype="salesorder" value="@salesorderid"/>
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

and this is the fetchXML of the main query:

```xml
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="salesorder" enableprefiltering="1">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="salesorderid" />
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="ownerid" operator="eq-userid" />
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="in">
        <value>0</value>
        <value>1</value>
      </condition>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Hope this will help someone.